# Как повторно отрисовать один и тот же виджет несколько раз в QtCreator？

Tags: qt, qtcreator, qwidget

Столкнулась с вопросом, как сделать так, что б при нажатии на кнопку в форме появлялся виджет, идентичный первому со всем его содержимым, и появился он сразу после первоначального. К примерк, есть виджет с формой авторизации пользователя и при нажатии на кнопку Login сразу за этой формой появлялась еще одна такая же форма.

Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Ну напишите класс виджета (наследуясь от QWidget и не забудьте секцию метаданных добавить), пропишите в нём все дочерние элементы. Далее в разных формах используйте ваш QObject/QWidget, который будет везде инициализироваться одинаковым образом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, копировать состояние данных формы вам не нужно. Тогда подойдет свой кастомный тип виджета - унаследуйтесь от `QWidget` (или тот тип, что вам нужен в качестве родителя, например - `QDialog`), в конструкторе настройте как необходимо и создавайте его так, как поступаете с остальными (создавайте сколько угодно раз через `new`, дочерним к родителям или непосредственно как окошко). Примерно такое:

```
class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWidget(const char *btnText, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    QPushButton *_btn;
    QLineEdit *_login;
    QLineEdit *_password;
};

MyWidget::MyWidget(const char *btnText, QWidget *parent /*= nullptr*/)
    : _btn(new QPushButton(btnText)), 
      _login(new QLineEdit),
      _password(new QLineEdit),
      QWidget(parent)
{
    _password->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);

    auto inputsLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    inputsLayout->addWidget(_login);
    inputsLayout->addWidget(_password);

    auto layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addLayout(inputsLayout);
    layout->addWidget(_btn);
    this->setLayout(layout);

    connect(_btn, &QPushButton::click, /* ... */ );
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня в проекте есть виджет, я его создал два раза с разными именами соответственно и отображаю их в разных местах программы, но функционал у них один.
Единственное что если нужна синхронизация между окнами то придется создавать ее самому... в одном обновил инфу, ее обновить в другом окне например..раз объекты разные...